# looping horizontally based on two criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in which I want to create a VBA code to write me the dates In ascending order in horizontally method but the problem when I activate the code, it gives me the date with the last criteria. my code is as follows:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim a As Range, ab As Range, b As Range, bc As Range
 Set ab = Range("B3:E3")
 Set bc = Range("A2:D2")
 For Each a In ab
 For Each b In bc
 If Cells(3, 1) <> "" Then
     Cells(3, a.Column) = Range("A3") + Cells(2, b.Column)
 Else
     Cells(3, a.Column) = ""
 End If
 Next
 Next
 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It would help to include the row and column headers in your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

yes, I changed the Ranges identification names, but the most important part is the solution.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
      On Error Resume Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      Dim cng As Range, rng As Range
      Set rng = Range("B3:E3")
      For Each cng In rng
      If Cells(3, 1) <> "" Then
            cng.Offset(0, 0).Value = cng.Offset(0, -1) + 1
      ElseIf Cells(3, 1) = "" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ""
      End If
      Next
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: the above do what i want in other way, but if any can solve the question with the same idea in the question, it will be new way to me to learn and apply. thank for all who participate.